# Procedure level variable losing value in do until loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a loop that adds cells to a range based on a couple of conditions.

1) the cell is either to the right or down of a cell that is already in the range,

2) the cell is the same color as a previously specified color.

```
Sub DefineContiguousRegion()

Dim c As Range
Dim areNewCells As Boolean

Do
    areNewCells = False
    For Each c In CurrentRange
        If (Intersect(CurrentRange, c.Offset(1)) Is Nothing) And c.Offset(1).Interior.ColorIndex = CurrentColor Then
            areNewCells = True
            CurrentRange = Union(CurrentRange, c.Offset(1))
        End If
        If (Intersect(CurrentRange, c.Offset(, 1)) Is Nothing) And c.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = CurrentColor Then
            areNewCells = True
            CurrentRange = Union(CurrentRange, c.Offset(, 1))
        End If
    Next
Loop Until areNewCells = False
```

The problem is that the variable areNewCells is being reset to out of context at the end of the For Each loop.  So the until condition is never fulfilled, even if the value is never set to true.

Why is this happening?  How can I fix it?

If someone can come up with an easier way of creating this range, that would be nice, but what I'm really looking for is a better understanding of variable scope/lifetime, as this is a learning project rather than a time sensitive work related one.

Comment: Have you stepped through and observed the value of `areNewCells` in the  Locals Window?

Comment: Yes.  I have a breakpoint at the "next" statement right before the Loop Until.  As soon as I get to the "next" statement, the locals window clears.

Comment: Where does CurrentRange get defined ?

Comment: `CurrentRange = Union(CurrentRange, c.Offset(1))` doesn't actually do anything but doesn't generate an error either. You need to use `Set CurrentRange = Union(CurrentRange, c.Offset(1))` to actually change the cells in the range

Comment: Thank you barrowc!  That fixed it!

Comment: Just as an explanation of barrowc's comment. Since you do not use the `Set` key word, the range `Union(CurrentRange, c.Offset(1))` does not  get assigned to `CurrentRange`. Instead the default property of `Union(CurrentRange, c.Offset(1))`  gets assigned to that of `CurrentRange`. For ranges, `Value` is the default property. (Well, technically that is not entirely true but outside `For Each` loops `Value` acts as the default property.)

Comment: @Rubikkon - See ["Always Use Option Explicit'](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201612290042356593265). Incorporating this principle will save you much troubleshooting in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

since you asked for *easier way*, you could consider the following code:

```
With CurrentRange
    For Each c In Union(.Offset(, .Columns.count).Resize(.Rows.count + 1, 1), .Offset(.Rows.count).Resize(1)) '<--| loop through wanted cells only
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = CurrentColor Then Set CurrentRange = Union(CurrentRange, c)
    Next c
End With
```

Comment: @Rubikon, did you get through it?